# prevent selenium from alt-tab when taking screenshot

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import uuid
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://google.com'
for _ in range(20):
    driver.get(url)
    fn = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".png"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img').screenshot(fn)
```

other than headless, how can I prevent selenium from alt-tab when it takes the screenshot?

the reason I can't use headless is because of some extension I have built.

Comment: what do you mean by "alt-tab"?

Comment: I am running the script and everytime it takes a screenshot, it alt-tabs me back to chrome

Comment: So you're trying to say that you want the script and the browser to be running while you're doing other tasks, but when the script takes the screen shot it brings the browser to focus on your screen and interrupts your other work?

Comment: @goalie1998 yes,exactly

Comment: Not sure there is a way

Comment: @goalie1998 there should be some code that can do it in `driver.execute_script(...)`

Comment: have you investigated why the system is redirecting you to a different app?  That seems like strange behavior.  Perhaps the script is attempting to write to a directory it doesn't have write permission for?  I suspect that if you understand why this is happening, you will be able to resolve that issue.